# how to wait for session loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using `next-auth` for user authentification, when the user signin I store the `accessToken` in the `session`

in my page `[trackId].js` each time the user updates the track the value of `refresh` (which is a useState hook) changes so `useEffect` runs and get the new track.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function refreshPage() {
      console.log(session); // <-- output in the image below
      await axiosPrivateWithToken(session.data.accessToken)
        .get(`/track/get/${trackId}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setGetedTrack(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("refreshPage for track has catched an error : ", error);
        });
    }
    refreshPage();
  }, [refresh]);
```

so far so good all works fine the problem is when the user enters the `URL` manually, I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accessToken')

and this is because when the window reloads the session is `loading` and does not have the `accessToken` yet, data is still `undefined`

[image]

any suggestions ? thank you for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking if session is defined each time you need it, a good pattern is this one, you declare an Auth component :

```
function Auth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  // if `{ required: true }` is supplied, `status` can only be "loading" or "authenticated"
  const router = useRouter();
  const { status } = useSession({ required: true, onUnauthenticated() {
    router.push('/login');
  }, })

  if (status === "loading") {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return children
}
```

And in your _app.tsx, you add it like this so session will always be defined:

```
  <Layout>
      {Component.auth ? (
        <Auth>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Auth>
      ) : (
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
  </Layout>
```

So if you need a Page where session has always to be defined, you juste have to add an Auth property to your page, for exmaple if you have a page named 'account' :

```
Account.auth = {
    
}
```

And then, session will always be defined in your page or you'll be redirect to `/login`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add `session.data.accessToken` to the dependency list, so it refreshes once you have your access token?

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function refreshPage() {
    if (!session.data || !session.data.accessToken) return;
    console.log(session); // <-- output in the image below
    await axiosPrivateWithToken(session.data.accessToken)
      .get(`/track/get/${trackId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setGetedTrack(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("refreshPage for track has catched an error : ", error);
      });
  }
  refreshPage();
}, [refresh, (session.data || { accessToken: '' }).accessToken]);
```